# In Firebase Analytics, are there any ways to know the source of 'direct'

Tags: android, iphone, firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

In Firebase Analytics conversion first-open, the referrer is direct. Is there a way to know the referrer of (direct)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If referrer is set to `direct`, there is no additional information on where the user came from. If there is any additional information, that will be specified in the referrer property.